# Generate new column in dataframe, based on group-event in nested groups

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I have a dataframe with three "main"-groups (x: 1, 2, 3), three groups within the main-groups (v: 2, 3 or 1) and some events within the main-groups (0 and 1 in y):

```
x <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)
v <- c(2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2)
y <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
df <- data.frame(x, v, y)
df

> df
  x v y
1 1 2 0
2 1 3 0
3 1 3 1
4 2 2 0
5 2 2 0
6 3 1 0
7 3 1 0
8 3 2 0
9 3 2 1
```

For example: In group 1 (x = 1) there are two more groups (v = 2 and v = 3), event y = 1 happens in group x = 1 and v = 3.

Now i want to generate a new column z, based on the events in y: if there is any y = 1 in one group, all cases in group v in x should get a 1 for z; else NA. How can z be generated this way? df should look like:

```
> df
  x v y  z
1 1 2 0 NA
2 1 3 0  1
3 1 3 1  1
4 2 2 0 NA
5 2 2 0 NA
6 3 1 0  1
7 3 1 1  1
8 3 2 0 NA
9 3 2 0 NA
```

I am grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>% group_by(x, v) %>% mutate(z = if(any(y == 1)) 1 else NA)
```

After grouping by `x` and `y`, the new column `z` is filled with `1`'s if there are any `1`'s in `y` and with `NA`'s otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
group_by(x, v) %>%
mutate(
z = ifelse(any(y == 1), 1, NA)
)
```